# Help verify a proof about "extension of monotone function"

Tags: real-analysis

> For any monotone function $g$ defined on a non-empty set $\Omega\subset\Bbb{R}$, show that there exists a monotone function $f$ defined on $\Bbb{R}$ such that $f=g$ on $\Omega$. The monotonicity of $f,g$ need not be strict

**My attempt** is as below (a bit lengthy so I prefer to type it in MS Word). I am not very confident about my proof. Can anyone help verify it? Also is there better (shorter) proof? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You would have a problem with $\tan x$ on $\Omega = (-\pi/2,\pi/2).$

Comment: Actually, @zhw. 's example seems to contradict the original claim (if you're not allowed to make the function infinite anywhere).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the case that $g$ is assumed to be bounded, then is the claim correct?

Comment: If $g$ is bounded or $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ are admissible values of $f$, then the claim is correct and at least your construction of $f$ is exactly what I would have done. I haven't checked over your proof, though.

Comment: Thank you! I examined the textbook again, it seems to extend the concept of monotonicity by allowing $f$'s codomain to be the extended real line $[-\infty,+\infty]$. E.g., in the case of $\tan x$ it allows $f(x)=+\infty$ on $[\pi/2, +\infty)$ and $f(x)=-\infty$ on $(+\infty,\pi/2]$ and it still considers $f$ as kind of monotone. Sorry that I did not make it clear in my question.

Comment: 1) would not necessarily be strict inequality relating $f(x_1)$ to $f(x_2)$.